# How to select a random word from a list using the 'Twit' library

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, bots

I'm learning javascript and Node all by myself. Right now what I'm trying to do is to make a twitter bot that tweets random sentences from a list. So far the code I have post a random number between 0 and 100:

```
console.log("Starting Bot");

var Twit = require('twit');

var config = require('./config');
var T = new Twit(config);

tweetBot();

function tweetBot() {

    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)

    var tweet= {
      status: 'This is a test ' + r
    }

    T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted);

    function tweeted(err, data, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Something went wrong!");
      } else {
      console.log("It worked!");
      }
   }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to get my bot to post a random word from a list of words already made. So far the code I've find to do that has been this one:

```
function random_word() {

  var word = [
   'tree',
   'fish',
   'apple',
   'cat'
  ];
  return word[Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length)];
}
```

I tried to add it to my code, change some things, rearrange it for it to work but no luck so far. If you have any ideas in how to make my bot to pick a random word to post it to Twitter, it'd be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Also, remember to add semicolons at the end of statements, like functions.  It doesn't matter in javascript, but it will matter in other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace r on the status definition with random_word().  That should work.